# "Object has no method 'getBounds'" error in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using this code to draw a point on a map:

```
function addPointToMap(pMap){
    var coordinates = new Array();

    // Style Point
    var style_blue = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
    style_blue.strokeColor = "blue"; 
    style_blue.fillColor = "blue"; 

    // Make Point
    coordinates.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(33, 33));
    var pointFeature =  new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(coordinates, null, style_blue);

    // Layer
    var pointsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Points Layer");
    pointsLayer.addFeatures([pointFeature]);
    pMap.addLayer(pointsLayer);         
}
```

I'm getting this error from the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object POINT(33, 33) has no method 'getBounds'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I received a similar error while adding a polygon (not a point) from raw WKT data. The error that there are no bounds occur because the object was of the wrong type.

When you call `addFeatures`, it expects an array of [`OpenLayers.Feature.Vector`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Feature/Vector-js.html) objects, which are created by [`Format.read`](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format-js.html#OpenLayers.Format.read).

```
var wkt_parser = new OpenLayers.Format.WKT();
var wkt_data_parsed = wkt_parser.read(some_raw_wkt_data_string);
layer.addFeatures([wkt_data_parsed]);
```

Comment: I totally forgot about this question. 
You are right, it was of the wrong object type.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to add a multipoint geometry:

```
function addPointToMap(pMap){
            var coordinates = new Array();

            // Style Point
            var style_blue = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style['default']);
            style_blue.strokeColor = "blue"; 
            style_blue.fillColor = "blue"; 

            // Make Point
            coordinates.push(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(lon, lat));
            var pointsGeometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.MultiPoint(coordinates);
            var pointFeature =  new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(pointsGeometry, null, style_blue);

            // Layer
            var pointsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Points Layer");
            pointsLayer.addFeatures([pointFeature]);
            pMap.addLayer(pointsLayer);         
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your map have a 'baselayer'? Otherwise you should add option 'alloverlays'=true to your map options. I'm not sure if this solves your problem though...

Comment: Also, try asking your question on gis.stackexchange.com , you might get better help there!